How to group by or partition by on multiple columns and assign each "group" a number or a variable?
So, I have the following table where
Col1 can have 2 values: A or B
Col2 can have 2 values: P or Q
Col3 can have 3 values: L, M or N
Roll_number is just a numeric Id number
Roll_number , Col1 , Col2, Col3
121212      ,    A ,    P,    L
131313      ,    A ,    P,    L
141414      ,    B ,    P,    M
525252      ,    A ,    Q,    L
626262      ,    B ,    P,    M
929292      ,    A ,    Q,    L
939393      ,    A ,    P,    N
232323      ,    B ,    Q,    L
090909      ,    B ,    P,    L
303030      ,    B ,    Q,    N
505050      ,    A ,    Q,    M
608960      ,    A ,    Q,    L

What I would like to have is the following after "grouping" by on Col1, Col2 and Col3:
Roll_number , Col1 , Col2, Col3, Group_Name
121212      ,    A ,    P,    L,          1
131313      ,    A ,    P,    L,          1

141414      ,    B ,    P,    M,          2
626262      ,    B ,    P,    M,          2

525252      ,    A ,    Q,    L,          3
929292      ,    A ,    Q,    L,          3
608960      ,    A ,    Q,    L,          3

939393      ,    A ,    P,    N,          4
232323      ,    B ,    Q,    L,          5
090909      ,    B ,    P,    L,          6
303030      ,    B ,    Q,    N,          7
505050      ,    A ,    Q,    M,          8

How do I achieve this?

I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Likely with DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1, col2, col3) as Group_Name but that will be dependent on whether your RDBMS supports the DENSE_RANK() window function.

Thanks @ThomA. I tagged SQL and MySQL.

Thanks @JNevill - Dense_rank() did work.

@GravityBoy what is logic behind your group name... what is you sequential priority column ? Is that Col1, Col2, Col3 or Col2, Col1, Col3 or something other ???

Stupid question ... Might be help this solution: https://dbfiddle.uk/D6Lzqnb_

I believe you can use dense_rank () function in MYSQL.
The ORDER BY clause can be adjusted as per your need. Dense_Rank() is a window function that ranks rows in partitions with no gaps in the ranking values.
select *, 

dense_rank() over(partition by col1, col2, col3 order by roll_number) as group_name

from table


Awesome, thank you so much! This helped.

@GravityBoy can you mark the answer as accepted then (clicking on the tick mark) and upvote (clicking on the upper arrow) ?

It is not quite clear what are the rules for group numbers assignment. One of the ways to give you the exact expected result with the sample data provided could be like this:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl( roll_number Varchar(6), col_1 varchar(1), col_2 varchar(1), col_3 varchar(1));
Insert Into tbl(roll_number, col_1, col_2, col_3)
VALUES ( '121212', 'A',    'P',    'L' ),
       ( '131313', 'A',    'P',    'L' ),
       ( '141414', 'B',    'P',    'M' ),
       ( '525252', 'A',    'Q',    'L' ),
       ( '626262', 'B',    'P',    'M' ),
       ( '929292', 'A',    'Q',    'L' ),
       ( '939393', 'A',    'P',    'N' ),
       ( '232323', 'B',    'Q',    'L' ),
       ( '090909', 'B',    'P',    'L' ),
       ( '303030', 'B',    'Q',    'N' ),
       ( '505050', 'A',    'Q',    'M' ),
       ( '608960', 'A',    'Q',    'L' );

... had to use some hardcodings to assigne groups 1, 2 and 3 ...
--      S Q L : 
SELECT   a.roll_number, a.col_1, a.col_2, a.col_3, 
         Case When a.col_1 = 'A' And cnt = 2 Then 1
              When a.col_1 = 'B' And cnt = 2 Then 2
              When a.col_1 = 'A' And cnt = 3 Then 3
         Else Count(Case When cnt = 1 Then 1 End) 
                    Over(Order By rn
                         Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) + 3
        End as grp
FROM   ( Select roll_number, col_1, col_2, col_3, 
                Row_Number() Over() as rn, 
                Count(roll_number) Over(Partition By col_1, col_2, col_3) as cnt
        From tbl
       ) a
ORDER BY grp, rn

/*    R e s u l t : 
roll_number col_1   col_2   col_3   grp
----------- ------- ------- ------ ----
121212      A       P       L         1
131313      A       P       L         1
141414      B       P       M         2
626262      B       P       M         2
525252      A       Q       L         3
929292      A       Q       L         3
608960      A       Q       L         3
939393      A       P       N         4
232323      B       Q       L         5
090909      B       P       L         6
303030      B       Q       N         7
505050      A       Q       M         8    */

