How to assign a random number between 1 and 3 for each group?
I am using Snowflake (or MySQL is also fine) and I would like to assign a random number between 1 and 3 (both inclusive) to an ID column based on which group they are in - so that the 1s, 2s and 3s are equally distributed in each group. For example,
Roll_number , Col1
121212      ,    A
131313      ,    A
141414      ,    B
525252      ,    A
626262      ,    B
929292      ,    A
939393      ,    A
232323      ,    B
090909      ,    A
303030      ,    B
505050      ,    A
608960      ,    A

What I would like to have is the following:
Roll_number , Col1 , Random_Number
121212      ,    A ,             1 
131313      ,    A ,             2
525252      ,    A ,             3
929292      ,    A ,             3
939393      ,    A ,             1
505050      ,    A ,             1
608960      ,    A ,             3
090909      ,    A ,             2

141414      ,    B ,             1
232323      ,    B ,             2
626262      ,    B ,             3
303030      ,    B ,             1

so that the 1s, 2s and 3s are equally distributed in groups A and B. Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

That's almost certainly not what you want.  You can do FLOOR(RAND()*3+1), but that's going to give you a different number every time you do a query.

@TimRoberts, thanks - I changed the language of my question. What I wanted was to have was equal distribution of 1, 2 and 3 in each group.

Window function with a rank and rand order?

Do you have to do this in SQL? In a real programming language you can extract each group into an array. Then you can shuffle the array randomly and assign 1,2,3 sequentlly to the array elements.

Yes, that's what you said in your question, but my comment still applies.  You need to add this value when each record is created.  Right?  What happens if new records arrive after you've assigned values?

Do always have modular 3 number of records in each group?

What is the purpose of doing this? There might be a better way.

@TimRoberts, its a fixed/static table - nothing new is added or removed.

@AllanWind, when you say rank and rand order - can you, please, show me an example?

Do you need the same result when you re-run the query?  Otherwise you need to store the random data somewhere.

The posted answer is close to what I had in mind.

@GravityBoy is this a duplicate for your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78916178/how-to-group-by-or-partition-by-on-multiple-columns-and-assign-each-group-a-nu

What is the difference between assigning random numbers (1-3) across the table vs within each group? it is the same thing, isn't it? It is possible (but not likely) to get all, say, 1 for all rows of the table or all rows of a group; it is random.

Use RN to generate a unique sequential number for each row within a group that you define by PARTITION BY Col1.
I added ((rn - 1) % 3) + 1 to evenly distribute numbers 1, 2, and 3 within each group. The rn - 1 part makes the ROW_NUMBER start from 0, and % 3 ensures the values cycle through 0, 1, 2. I added 1 to make it shift to 1, 2, 3.
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    Roll_number VARCHAR(20),
    Col1 CHAR(1)
)


INSERT INTO your_table (Roll_number, Col1) VALUES
('121212', 'A'),
('131313', 'A'),
('141414', 'B'),
('525252', 'A'),
('626262', 'B'),
('929292', 'A'),
('939393', 'A'),
('232323', 'B'),
('090909', 'A'),
('303030', 'B'),
('505050', 'A'),
('608960', 'A')



Records: 12  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT
        Roll_number,
        Col1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY RAND()) AS rn
    FROM
        your_table
)
SELECT
    Roll_number,
    Col1,
    ((rn - 1) % 3) + 1 AS Random_Number
FROM
    RankedData
ORDER BY
    Col1, Roll_number




Roll_number
Col1
Random_Number




090909
A
3


121212
A
2


131313
A
2


505050
A
1


525252
A
1


608960
A
1


929292
A
3


939393
A
2


141414
B
2


232323
B
1


303030
B
1


626262
B
3



fiddle

Would it make sense to order by (select NULL) to get true randomness?

CTE is obviously excess in your query, you may use according expression immediately.

Assuming roll_number is evenly distributed and itself can be considered "random":
select
    Roll_number,
    Col1,
    Roll_number div 3 + 1 as Random_Number
from mytable


You can use a window function like ROW_NUMBER() in combination with modulo to get what you want: that each group would have an equal number of 1s, 2s, and 3s:
SELECT
    Roll_number,
    Col1,
    ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY RANDOM()) - 1) % 3) + 1 AS Random_Number
FROM
    your_table;


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
